# Subclassing dict and implementing __getitem__ for nested class (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, subclassing

I am currently trying to implement a subclass (called 'Pointer_dict') for the python dictionary class `dict`. The purpose of this class is to save memory when creating copies of dictionaries and changing their values without changing the original dicitonary. Which is why, I don't use `deepcopy()`.

The Pointer_dict class is supposed to take an existing dictionary and upon call (e.g. `tmp['foo']`) return the original value if it exists (otherwise KeyError), but return its own value, if that value was overwritten before.

For demonstration:

```py
original = { 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2 }
pointer_dict = Pointer_dict(origin=original)

print(pointer_dict['foo']) # 1
pointer_dict['foo'] = 10
print(pointer_dict['foo']) # 10
print(original['foo']) # 1
```

So it points at its own values, when they were set, but points towards the original dictionary, when it was not set.
Problem with this appears for nested dictionaries.
Assume we have:

```py
original = { 'foo': 1, 'bar': { 'foobar': 2, 'barfoo': 3 } }
pointer_dict = Pointer_dict(origin=original)

print(pointer_dict['foo']) # 1
pointer_dict['bar']['foobar'] = 10
print(pointer_dict['bar']['foobar']) # 10
print(original['bar']['foobar']) # 2
```

Since we only set `['bar']['foobar']` the pointer_dict only contains `{ 'bar': { 'foobar': 10} }`, because it is not supposed to copy the original values (due to memory saving), but just point at them.
So the problem I'm facing now, if I want to print either `pointer_dict` itself or `pointer_dict['bar']` I want the output to look like:

```py
{ 'foo': 1, 'bar': { 'foobar': 10, 'barfoo': 3 } } # print(pointer_dict)
{ 'foobar': 10, 'barfoo': 3 } # print(pointer_dict['bar'])
```

So my questions is, **how can I implement the __getitem__ and the __repr__ method with the return value being a mixture of its own values and original values?**

If I use a normal dictionary as a return-value, then nested lists won't work, because after one __getitem__ call, the return value is a dictionary and then my own __getitem__ method won't be called for deeply nested lists, so it'd return the wrong values.

My approach so far was like this (I have not yet tried implementing `__repr__`, because my previous method didn't work):

```
class Pointer_Dict(dict):
    def __init__(self, mapping={}, /, **kwargs):
        self.origin = kwargs['kwargs']
        super().__init__(mapping)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value) -> None:
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = Pointer_Dict(value, kwargs=self.origin[key])
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            val_dict = super().__getitem__(key)
            try:
                val_orig = self.origin[key]
                if isinstance(val_orig, dict):
                    return Pointer_Dict(mapping=val_dict, kwargs=val_orig)
            except KeyError:
                return val_dict
        except KeyError:
            try:
                val_orig = self.origin[key]
                if isinstance(val_orig, dict):
                    return Pointer_Dict(kwargs=val_orig)
                return val_orig
            except KeyError:
                raise KeyError(key)
        return val_dict
```

My thoughts here were to make an recursive approach, where it would call the `__getitem__` as long as the value is still a dictionary/subclass of a dictionary and returns the value only when faced with something that is not a dictionary.
... But that did not work, I do not get the right values and I'm a little lost on how to solve the problem...

So I'm open for any new suggestions on how to solve this!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a job for [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap).

Comment: What you want to achieve is complex, and while it may have superficially worked in some tests, it is full of problems if you try to use this in "realword".

Python's `collection.ChainMap` does this correctly, but only apply to the root dictionary: it never inspect the values to see if they are dicts or try to change them: the advantage: it will work without bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry- I won´t have the time (or will) to fix all your code. You got a good starting point.

As I commented above, this kind of code is error prone, and there are *lots* of edge cases. Some of which you overlook, some of others are due to intricacies in the way Python do things and you might have just not known about them.

So, first things first: `collections.ChainMap`  does what you describe. But it never fiddles with the dictionary contents: it is not recursive - if a nested value is a plain dictionary, it will just be a plain dictionary.

Second thing: one should avoid inherit directly from `dict`. It has some traps - primarily because the internal implementation will *not always* go through user defined `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` in the user class, as native methods just access the dicionary contents directly (i.e. `__iter__`, `get`, `setdefault` and even `__len__` methods won't work and you'd have to write all of those, and maybe some more). The workaround that is to inherit from `collections.UserDict` instead of inheriting directly from `dict`: it is a thin pure Python wrapper around native dicts, but that will channel all data access through `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`: so you can get away with only those. Also, it uses a native plain  `dict` in its `.data` attribute, and you can access that in your methods directly if you think you should.

Third thing: This may be the main reason why your code is not behaving as you expect: you always check if an object is a dict with `isinstance(obj, dict)` :this will *also be true* if your object is a `Pointer_Dict` instance, since it subclasses dict.
Changing to inherit from `UserDict` would fix this statements, but not your logic: there are points there where you will maybe want to perform a different action if the object being tested is *already* a `Pointer_Dict` - so you probably want to test for that first. And then test if the other object is an instance of `collections.abc.Mapping` instead of `dict` directly, as this will make your code work with other flavours of dictionaries as well.

Fourth thing: you are wrapping your values with Pointr_Divcts both when setting them, and *again* when reading them (creating new objetcs all the time. If the objective would be saving memory, that is not the best approach). Most of the problems that cause will be resolved if you properly test if the values are already `Pointer_Dict`, like I spotted in "Third thing" above. But you will get different results if you wrap then when setting *and* retrieving, or just when retrieving, and you have to check what you really want.
Anothe thing: dictionaries already existing in the original wrapped `dict` would not be converted to `Pointer_Dict` in your implementation, as the Python's dict contructors won't call its own `__setitem__`. If you do inherit from `collections.UserDict` that will probably be fixed.

Fith thing: this is not related to your logic, but it is a common "Python trap" -  in the line
 `def __init__(self, mapping={}, /, **kwargs):`, the default value `{}` for mapping is a trap, as it is a single object that will be shared across all your instances of `Pointer_Dict`. The correct way to do this is set the default to `None` and create an empty dict *inside* the method: this new dict will be created each time the code is executed, and all instances will have independent values:

```
...
def __init__(self, mapping={}, /, **kwargs):
    if mapping is None:
         mapping = {}
    ...
...
```

(Also, the way you are using `kwargs` is strange: your `__init__` needs to have a named parameter called `kwargs` as it is - check if you really need that)

So, I spotted those on a first read. There may be more problems, and some of these are not simple fixes - they depend on the final behavior you want of your code.

I am the author of mapping classes that have similar features, and I can asure you that before getting to "production quality" this kind of logic needs a lot of testing. (But I don't have a "nested chainmap" like the one you want here, otherwise I'd just tell you to use my implementation). Mine are published in pypi as "extradict", and you can pip-install it  - the source code for those may get you some extra insights - https://github.com/jsbueno/extradict .

oh - sorry - just now I perceived I pointed problems in your implementation, but did not even touch in the new behaviors you are asking for. Sorry for that - but if you can get these fixes in, them getting your desired behaviors with plain `if...else` code in your methods should become a lot easier, as you won't face unexpected results anymore.

Best wishes there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the many insights, I'll have a look into the extradict code and fix my current code... there is much to learn..!